# Applying multiple colors to a single element in google charts

Tags: javascript, charts

The following refers to a javascript script in a c# cshtml page.

I have customized(with the help of this forum) a google charts, bar chart to allow me to click each column and bring me to another page. I now wish to edit the colours of these columns but they way google charts lays out their bar charts seems to make this a bit awkward.

Under every heading/column they seem to assume you will put multiple values(bars) and you can customize the colour of the bars under each heading/column. But I have one value for every heading and thus when a apply a colour to Heading 1 Value 1 it will apply that colour to the first(and in my case only value) under every other heading/column.

I'm wondering is there an id type value I can hard code in and assign a colour to that id.

The script I have written is below and all four Bars are blue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @{
    <text>
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                      ['Job State', 'link', 'Number of Jobs'],
                      ['Total Jobs', 'LINK', @Model.VARIABLE],
                      ['Live Jobs', 'LINK', @Model.VARIABLE],
                      ['Draft Jobs', 'LINK', @Model.VARIABLE],
                      ['Closed Jobs', 'LINK', @Model.VARIABLE]
                    ]);
                    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                    view.setColumns([0, 2]);

                    var options = {
                        title: "Job State Overview",
                        width: 600, height: 400,
                        vAxis: { title: "Number Of Jobs" },
                        hAxis: { title: "Job States " },
                        colors: ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'black']
                    };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
                        document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                    chart.draw(view, options);

                    var selectHandler = function (e) {
                        window.location = data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0]['row'], 1);
                    }

                    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
                }
                </text>
                        }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack to get around it but Its not ideal as it shrinks the sizes of the bars:

Replace the input array as follows:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                      ['Job State', 'link', 'Total Jobs', 'Live Jobs', 'Draft Jobs', 'Closed Jobs'],
                      ['Total Jobs', '@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Activities/level1?job_Type_Id=5"))', @Model.jobCount, 0, 0, 0],
                      ['Live Jobs', '@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Activities/level1?job_Type_Id={0}",(int)JobState.GoLive))', 0,@Model.liveJobCount, 0, 0],
                      ['Draft Jobs', '@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Activities/level1?job_Type_Id={0}",(int)JobState.Draft))', 0, 0,@Model.draftJobCount, 0],
                      ['Closed Jobs', '@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Activities/level1?job_Type_Id={0}",(int)JobState.Closed))', 0, 0, 0,@Model.closedJobCount]
                    ]);
```